# Ios - baas - complex algorithm response times

Tags: ios, firebase

I am going to build an ios application for my workplace that will be the home for 300-400 users on a daily basis.

Between a multitude of features, one of them will involve allowing about 100 remote sales reps to requests support from IT support staffs who will have access to a feed of the requesta depending in their proximity to the request.

I'm very familiar with the relational dabatase model and was hoping I could have parse but considering it will be going offline, I was thinking about leveraging firebase as well as it's geofire features.

My concern, and a big one, is the impact that performing these types of queries that are custom to each user will have on the loading times and overall app experience.

I'm relatively new to IOS programming but extremely excited to have the opportunity to tackle a project that seems above my abilities.

Should I be considering a different baas or be worried about complex queries diminishing from a positive user experience?

Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: there's really only firebase, just move on with it.

Comment: Joe, any comments on postgresql vs firebase?